# My website was showing CSS fine until I did collectstatic - Django

Tags: python, django, collectstatic

My website was doing everything well and showing all the CSS until I ran `collectstatic` on it. Now everything is how it would look if CSS didn't exist. Is there any solution to this? Or is there some way I can delete the `collectstatic` to get back the previous thing?

I followed this tutorial to host this website: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

Here's my `settings.py`(only the last bit where I set the static and the media stuff):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = []
MEDIA_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
LOGIN_URL = '/main/user_login/'
```

Comment: Maybe include a [mcve]?

Comment: Share settings file as pertains to static file path. Also the network error for the missing static assets.

Comment: Right-o, editing the post.

Comment: try killing last slash on this line: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static>>>>/<<<<')` - comparing to my projects.

Comment: @Marc But I get an error then: `?: (urls.E006) The STATIC_URL setting must end with a slash.`

Comment: The funny thing is, `admin` can access static, but not my main website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so as you mentioned it stopped working after you ran collectstatic command.
collectstatic command makes Django looks for all static files in your apps and collects them in a single directory which is STATIC_ROOT. (In production it needs a single directory for all the static files)

Put the directories containing your static files into the STATICFILES_DIRS.

You also have to include your static urls in your urls.py

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [your paths go here]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

After including your static directories into the STATICFILES_DIRS array and including the static urls in your urls.py, use the command collectstatic and then it should work.